# Se o campo tem DEFAULT ele deve ser NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, null, default

#### Situação

Estava adicionando mais algumas colunas em um tabela e cai deste pensamento. Por padrão aqui deixamos todos os campos podendo ter valor `NULL`, contudo se ele tem um `DEFAULT` ele ira inserir o `DEFAULT` no lugar de `NULL`.

#### Questão

Se o campo tem um `DEFAULT` ele também deve estar setado como `NOT NULL`? ou é indiferente?

Comment: Depende também da aplicação, se tu podes setar o valor como nulo ele não vai inserir o *default*, vai inserir `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

São coisas distintas.

O `DEFAULT` apenas faz um *auto insert* se a inserção não tiver um valor para aquela coluna, mas nada impede de você aplicar um `NULL` nela depois disto em outra operação, se não houver uma cláusula `NOT NULL`. Inclusive no `INSERT` se você explicitamente disser que quer colocar um `NULL`, o `DEFAULT` não será considerado e o nulo será aplicado se não for definida esta restrição.

Então se quer restringir nulos, escreva isto na modelagem, não confie em uma operação transitória. O `DEFAULT` é só um facilitador, não um restritor.

Na verdade eu pensaria se vale essa ideia que tudo deveria ser `NULL` por padrão. Eu acho que deveria ser o contrário. Apenas quando há casos claros onde o `NULL` é útil é que ele deveria ser permitido. E raramente deveria ser útil.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).